# Javascript animation without jquery

Tags: javascript, animation

I am fiddling with [this](http://javascript.info/tutorial/animation) site for a day now and I am really struggling in one thing. I can reverse the animations quite easily, when I modify the `function move` so that if stop is negative `-stop-(-stop*delta)+"px"` and it works. somewhat.. For `easeOut(bounce)` it works good. But when I use linear the items bounce to the position I define as stop and then with the linear effect it comes back to the previous position. Can anyone help me how to easily reverse the animations that it WORKS?

Thank you!

Comment: could you please provide jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: Hold on. I'll prepare it right now.

Comment: here is the fiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/bd59y61h/](https://jsfiddle.net/bd59y61h/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like make a few comments on you code:

- you shoud add everywhere `;` after end of row. This is a good practice.
- in your case for fix issue you should set `start: 0` instead of `start: 200`. It needs because you set your `item` element as `style="left:200px"`

So it should be

```
document.getElementById('item').onclick = function (e) {
    e.target.move({
        direction: "left",
        delta: linear,
        stop: -200,
        duration: 600,
        start: 0    // instead of 200
    });
};
```

Here my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bd59y61h/1/)

Comment: I'm really glad that I've helped you

Answer (score 1):

I made this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7nv1xttq/1/).

Javascript

```
 var max = false;

function move(elem) {


  var left = 0

  if(max)
      left = 100;
  function frame() {

      if(!max)
      {
    left++  // update parameters 
      }
      else
      {
      left--
      }

    elem.style.left = left + 'px' // show frame 

    if (left == 100)  // check finish condition
    {
        clearInterval(id)
        max = true;
    }
      if(max == true && left == 0)
      {
                  clearInterval(id)
        max = false;
      }
  }

  var id = setInterval(frame, 10) // draw every 10ms

  };
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I know you were first to answer my question but after you posted it I posted a fiddle of my "library". I forgot to mention I am using the whole functions collection in a prototype function. Nevertheless thank you very much for your effort!